# Max-height scales image perfectly in FF, but Chrome has scrollbars

Tags: image, cross-browser, css

So I want a page that's nothing but a square image which scales up to the height of the window. Fine, great, I do:

```
img
{
   max-height:100%;
   height:100%;
   width:auto;   
}
```

and stick an  in a center-aligned div. Firefox loves it, but insists on the height:100%. Chrome doesn't need that, but adds a little bit of height to the page and so a scrollbar pops up. The whole page itself is still rendering identically down to the last pixel, but Chrome seems to think its window is a little heightier than it actually is. What's going on?

Comment: Things I would check: `margin` and `padding` being zero on all elements, including `html` and `body`.

Comment: There we go. It was body margin that did it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `margin` and `padding` on the `html` and `body` elements -- often a hidden source of pain!

Yes, I know this was in my comment, but this way the question looks answered :-)